# GPU Driver Issue That Causes Black Screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, crash, log

I am suffering that my screen goes black screen and my computer is completely frozen. I could not figure out what causes it but when I looked the logs I saw this error 9 in a row:
"[drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership"
What is that error means? Is it causes this error? If so how to fix it?

Comment: there's quite a lot about that error https://www.google.com/search?q=drm%3Anv_drm_master_set+[nvidia_drm]]+ERROR+[nvidia-drm]+[GPU+ID+0x00000100]+Failed+to+grab+modeset+ownership but it seems that could be an expected error? The blank screen issue, for me, has always been the wrong driver version. It may be out of date information now as I haven't had an nvidia card in years, for this reason, but you probably need to check exactly what driver version should work with your specific card.

Comment: Have you tried disabling secureboot in UEFI?

Comment: @SHawarden I check it in nvidia's site and installed correct version I guess

Comment: @CipherMenial Yes Ive disabled